# Limit the number of table cells per line

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i already created a pagination script but i've a problem when printing .. i'd like to print every 3 records in new line here is my `while` loop .

```
echo '<table cellspacing="12px" id="table">';
echo '<tr>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{

 echo ' <td><div class="data1r1"><span class="datamore">'.$row['title'].'</span></div></td>';
}
echo '</tr>';

echo '</table>';
```

i'm guessing if there is any idea to break line after every 3 records printed .

Comment: use counter and when the %3 == 0 do break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a counter(`$brk_cnt`) for calculating multiples of 3, then :

```
$brk_cnt = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
 echo ' <td>
        <div class="data1r1"><span class="datamore">'.$row['title'].'</span></div>
        </td>';

 //break or print <tr> condition
 if(++$brk_cnt % 3 == 0)
 {
    echo '</tr><tr>';
 }
}
```

Comment: @user3801289 : no probs...drop a comment if u face any issue! :)